# Plotting with while loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a some x and y coordinates like this:

```
x = [None, 5, 7, None, None, 9]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want a while loop to go through each list item in turn and plot a circle marker if it has an `x` and `y` coordinate and then the plot must stay there as it continues to plot more values, eventually it will have plotted every value from the lists.

Code:

```
i = 0
while i < 100:
    plt.plot((b[i]), (a[i]), marker='o')
    plt.ion()
    plt.pause(1)
    i += 1
```

Some reason, it seems to plot the marker and then it disappears, any ideas?

Comment: Do you want it to pause after each dot? You could simply feed it the list of elements preprocessed.

Comment: It's suppose to replicate data that is on a 1 second interval, so it needs to be shown with the pause.

Answer (score 4):

You question gives lists `x` and `y` and then uses `a` and `b` in the loop, so I'll just make something up for `a` and `b` and assume you have the filtering out of None's working.

```
a = [1, 5, 7, 1, 1, 9]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

You just need to set interactive once - not over and over in the loop. But this isn't the cause of the problem - just saying

```
plt.ion()

for (x, y) in zip(a,b):
    plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o')
    plt.pause(1)
```

What I observe is that the points are showing up - but the scale changes to show the new point - others are off the screen. If I zoom out enough all the points are actually there.

You may wish to give some thought to your axes scale; something like

```
plt.xlim([min(a)-1, max(a)+1])
plt.ylim([min(b)-1, max(b)+1])
```

should make all your data fit on the same plot without points seeming to disappear

[image]